# nginx docker image comments out ssl options

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy, docker-network

I have encountered a very peculiar problem with the latest docker nginx image. It looks like something is commenting out my ssl options, when I mount a file in a container. I tried renaming the file and also mounting in via nginx.conf or sites-enabled, but it only led to it being commented out again. The only logs, that I could gather from these problems is this shell script execution. Could someone point me in the right direction on how I can troubleshoot this further?

```
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
```

My nginx configuration file:

[image]

[image]
:

Docker-compose nginx block:

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    hostname: ghost-nginx
    ports:
     # - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
    #  - ./nginx/ssl/yourhost.xyz.key:/etc/nginx/yourhost.xyz.key:ro
    #  - ./nginx/ssl/yourhost.xyz.crt:/etc/nginx/yourhost.xyz.crt:ro
      - /usr/ghost/conf/ghost.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/ghost.conf
    #  - /usr/ghost/conf/ghost1.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default1.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/Mydomain/fullchain.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/tildawn.nts.am/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/Mydomain/privkey.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/tildawn.nts.am/privkey.pem
    #  - /usr/proxy_zt/zt.conf:/etc/nginx/site-enabled/zt.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf:/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf
      - /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem
    #  - ./etc/nginx/conf.d/ghost.conf:/usr/ghost/conf/ghost.conf
    #links:
    #  - ghost
    networks:
      my_prod_net:
    restart: always
```

**How I tried to solve the issue.**

- I tried changing the file name and moved it to sites-enabled, conf.d and nginx. Unfortunately, it didn't help to solve the issue.
- I also tried rebuilding the image and changing the file inside the container. That worked, but all progress was lost after a restart.

Comment: First of all I can assure you that NGINX does not comment out anything in your configuration. Furthermore I as not able to reproduce this. Where does `default.conf` comes from? In your `docker-compose` I can only see the `ghost.conf`? and your screenshots are `cating` the `default.conf` file.